# Doctrine 2, ManyToMany search

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have 2 Doctrine tables that are linked with a ManyToMany relationship.

Table: entries

TabLe: tags

I would like to be able to find the entries that have multiple or one tag(s) matching every tags that I input.

Ex: En entry "foo" have the tag "1" and "2". If I try to find every entries by the tag "1", I find this entry, if I do another search for both "1" and "2" I find it again, but if I add a search for the tag "3", then the value is not matched.

So far I have found some easy methods to implement such thing with an OR, but it doesn't give me the results I want and I don't really know how I could make that kind of search with Doctrine 2.

Normaly I would use the relation table to do that, but I don't know if it's possible under Doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure if I understood, but try if this works:

```
//class EntryRepository

public function yourFunction($tags)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
       ->innerJoin("o.Tags", "t", "WITH", "t.name IN :tags")
           ->setParameter("tags", $tags)
       ...
}
```

This will return entries that have at least one of the tags in $tags array. If that is what you want, you might also play with

```
->addSelect( "COUNT(t.id) as HIDDEN relevance")->groupBy("o.id")
->orderBy("relevance")
```

That would return results in order of how many tags are matched, but I didn't test it.

Comment: This is for an OR. It will match any entries that have at least 1 of the tags. What I want is an AND, that will return all entires that have all the tags. What I have right now that works is 1 INNER JOIN per tags. But I would be looking for a better solution if any exists. (And thanks for the relevance thing, going to use it somewhere else!)

Comment: Ok, I get it now what you want. afaik, you can't do it much simpler, using subquery would make code more unreadable. But even if you do that, then you would loose "orderBy(relevance)" because query would return results that match all of the tags.